# Invalidate not calling onDraw()

Tags: java, android, xml, drawing, invalidation

I am trying to call onDraw() whenever drawCircle() is pressed. I know that it is being called (by onClick in xml) because I get the message: "drawCircle pressed". The problem however, is that invalidate is not calling onDraw() which would draw a circle at a random place on the canvas, with a random color. I have tried placing the invalidate in DrawView and having drawCircle in my activity call that method but it also does not work. Any ideas why invalidate is not calling onDraw?

Thanks

In my XML I have defined my View:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" />

<com.example.genraterandomcircle.DrawView
    android:id="@+id/drawView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/generateBtnId"
    android:background="#000000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/generateBtnId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/drawView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:onClick="drawCircle"
    android:text="@string/generateBtnStr" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clearBtnId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/generateBtnId"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/generateBtnId"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/drawView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:onClick="clearCircles"
    android:text="@string/clearBtnStr" />
```

GenerateCircles.java:

```
package com.example.genraterandomcircle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class GenerateCircles extends Activity
{

    DrawView dv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_generate_circles);
        dv = new DrawView(this);
    }

    public void drawCircle(View v)
    {
        System.out.println("drawCircle pressed");

        dv.invalidate();
    }

    public void clearCircles(View v)
    {
        System.out.println("clear pressed");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.generate_circles, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The DrawView Class:

```
package com.example.genraterandomcircle;

import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DrawView extends View
{
    Canvas c;
    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Random random = new Random();
    Bitmap bm;

    public DrawView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context)
    {

        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        c = new Canvas(bm);

        System.out.println("hi there");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, canvas.getWidth() / 2, 0, null);

        p.setColor(Color.rgb(random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255)));
        canvas.drawCircle(random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()), random.nextInt(canvas.getHeight()),
                    random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth() / 4), p);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

instead of

```
dv = new DrawView(this);
```

in your onCreate use:

```
dv = (DrawView)findViewById(R.id.drawView1);
```

your not using the drawview that is in the layout that you set to the content view

Comment: This is working fine but do u think  setWillNotDraw(false); would work if not then why?? The object of that view is not able to call the invalidate() method is there any reason behind that if you have any answer please put it .

Comment: You just made me realise I'm not insane and going mad after half a day wondering why my onTouch with an invalidate call is working in my custom view yet a method call on the view fired from an an accelerometer listener in the activity wasn't causing a redraw. I'd created my view in he activity in usual java style thus as you say, different references. Ive not done that for years!!! :)

Comment: Thank you JRowan, thought was not going to be able to finish my hw! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You save my time,thanks a lot.I using ValueAnimator in my custom view and call start animation function in my activity.I was trying to make a very simple animation. I declared my object reference as MyCustomView(this). I solved it thanks to you.